# how to map this given json data in react js

Tags: json, reactjs

hello this is my json data and from this i just need the country name and value .. how to map this?

json

```
{
"fact": [
          {
            "dims": {
                      "COUNTRY": "Afghanistan",
                      "GHO": "Estimated number of people (all ages) living with HIV",
                      "YEAR": "2019"
                    },
            "Value": "11 000 [4300–38 000]"
          },
          {
            "dims": {
                      "COUNTRY": "Afghanistan",
                      "GHO": "Estimated number of people (all ages) living with HIV",
                      "YEAR": "2018"
                    },
            "Value": "10 000 [4200–33 000]"
          },
          {
            "dims": {
                      "COUNTRY": "Afghanistan",
                      "GHO": "Estimated number of people (all ages) living with HIV",
                      "YEAR": "2017"
                    },
            "Value": "9200 [4000–29 000]"
          },
```

react code

```
function current() {
const tag = Data.map((e) => {
    return <h1>{e.COUNTRY}</h1>;
});
return <div className='map'>{tag}</div>;
```

}

it would be very helpful if you can help me with this..

Comment: map over the fact like ```Data.fact.map(...)```

Answer (score 0):

considering your data is the object with the fact list .

```
const tag = data.fact.map((item, index) => {
    return <h1 key={index}>{item.dims.COUNTRY}</h1>;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Map over the fact array and in your map access the dims object.

```
const tag = Data.fact.map((e, key) => {
   return <h1 key={key}>{e.dims.COUNTRY}</h1>;
});
```

```js
const Example = () => {

  const Data = {
    fact: [
      {
        dims: {
          COUNTRY: "Afghanistan",
          GHO: "Estimated number of people (all ages) living with HIV",
          YEAR: "2019"
        },
        Value: "11 000 [4300–38 000]"
      },
      {
        dims: {
          COUNTRY: "Afghanistan",
          GHO: "Estimated number of people (all ages) living with HIV",
          YEAR: "2018"
        },
        Value: "10 000 [4200–33 000]"
      },
      {
        dims: {
          COUNTRY: "Afghanistan",
          GHO: "Estimated number of people (all ages) living with HIV",
          YEAR: "2017"
        },
        Value: "9200 [4000–29 000]"
      }
    ]
  };

  const tag = Data.fact.map((e, key) => {
    return <h1 key={key}>{e.dims.COUNTRY}</h1>;
});

  return (
    <div>
      {tag}
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```